# JQuery dialog leaving HTML in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JQuery so please forgive the obvious noobish title. I'm really not sure how to describe this but basically, what I'm seeing with firebug after I open a dialog box is a lot of these:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all " style="display: none; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1006; outline: 0px none; height: auto; width: 400px; top: 137px; left: 436px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-3">
```

There are at least 100 of them that I can see, one for each time I open a dialog.

Is there a way to stop this? I've noticed that the more dialogs I open, the slower the system becomes. I'm not sure this is the cause but I'm suspect.

Comment: When you close the dialog do destroy of dialog,

Comment: I'm using `$( this ).dialog( "close" );$( this ).dialog('destroy').remove();` but they are still bubbling up

Comment: i don't remember but you need to destroy it in the close event of dialog i believe.

Comment: Also are you creating the dialog each time, or just doing a show, can you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but I think I am creating a dialog each time.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.com is a HTML/CSS/JS web-based scratch pad.  It's very easy way to share your work with others on this site.

Comment: PSL, I think you are right, it needs to be destroyed in the close function. If you'd like to post your answer, I'd give you the credit.

Comment: @NaN Sure will set up a fiddle and do.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's working great now and the site is so much faster. :)

Comment: @NaN Added an answer with a demo... See if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a jquery ui dialog comes with a lot of overhead which jquery uses for various fatures of dialogues like resize on all directions, plugin transformed dialog itself (for reuse later)  etc.., so if you are creating the dialog every time you need to destroy them as well. And you need to destroy them once the close event on the dialog is complete which you can listed by subscribing to the [close event of dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close).

Something like this:

```
$(':input').on('click', function () {
    $('<div  title="Basic dialog" style="display:none">  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the     x icon.</p></div>').dialog({
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy'); //destroy it  on every close
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DNfwu/)**

Comment: Thanks again, my friend! All day, I've chasing odd behavior and this was the ticket all the way around!

Comment: @NaN Glad it was of help... :) i used to use jquery dialogs long back but then dtopped using jquery ui stuffs for these kind of maintenance issues. :)